# Execute a batch file after installation and display its output on a custom page before Finished page in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

A `cmd` output can be shown within Inno Setup UI using this solution:
[Embedded CMD in Inno Setup installer (show command output on a custom page)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56910906/850848)

My problem is that I want to execute a batch file in `[Run]` section (i.e.) after installation.

Also, I want its output to be displayed in Inno Setup UI, but from documentation I see that `[Run]` will be executed after installation and before final dialog is displayed.

So how can I show a custom page after installation, which will display all the output from the batch executed from `[Run]` section?

I tried to call the `CustomPage` setup via `BeforeInstall` flag in `Run` section, but the custom page is displayed for a second and then it returns back to Installing page.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to call the code from `BotonIniciarOnClick` from [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    BotonIniciarOnClick(nil);
  end;
end;
```

*(of course, you better rename the function, as its name now does not make sense – and remove its useless argument)*