# Create a button on Inno Setup custom wizard page to interrupt an program executed from the installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am creating a setup package using Inno Setup to run my cmd script. Using the articles available on Stack Overflow, I have managed to create a custom page that displays the output of the script on the setup wizard. However, during the script execution phase, I can't move the wizard window and can't even click on it. Here is the link that I used to create the custom page.
[Embedded CMD in Inno Setup installer (show command output on a custom page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910906/embedded-cmd-in-inno-setup-installer-show-command-output-on-a-custom-page/56912589)

Now, I want two things:

1. To be able to move the wizard window during the script execution phase.
2. Add a button to the custom page that passes <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> command to script that will stop the script execution.

For your reference, I am using following code in iss file.

```pascal
[Code]
// Add next button on ready to install page.
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // On fresh install the last pre-install page is "Select Program Group".
  // On upgrade the last pre-install page is "Read to Install"
  // (forced even with DisableReadyPage)
  // 1. Change text on Finish page
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := 'Setup has finished running the ResetWU script on this computer. Please restart your computer and check for Windows updates again. Click Finish to exit the setup wizard.';
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption := 'Finishing the ResetWU script wizard';
  // 2. Change button caption on ready-to-install and Finish pages.
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectProgramGroup) or (CurPageID = wpReady) then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext)
    // On the Finished page, use "Finish" caption.
  else if (CurPageID = wpFinished) then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish)
    // On all other pages, use "Next" caption.
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
end;

// Embed installation bat into installation progress page
var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  ProgressListBox: TNewListBox;

function SetTimer(
  Wnd: LongWord; IDEvent, Elapse: LongWord; TimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

function KillTimer(hWnd: LongWord; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  ProgressFileName: string;

function BufferToAnsi(const Buffer: string): AnsiString;
  var
    W: Word;
    I: Integer;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
    for I := 1 to Length(Buffer) do
    begin
      W := Ord(Buffer[I]);
      Result[(I * 2)] := Chr(W shr 8); { high byte }
      Result[(I * 2) - 1] := Chr(Byte(W)); { low byte }
    end;
  end;

procedure UpdateProgress;
  var
    S: AnsiString;
    I, L, Max: Integer;
    Buffer: string;
    Stream: TFileStream;
    Lines: TStringList;
  begin
    if not FileExists(ProgressFileName) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Progress file %s does not exist', [ProgressFileName]));
      end
    else
      begin
        try
          { Need shared read as the output file is locked for writting, }
          { so we cannot use LoadStringFromFile }
          Stream := TFileStream.Create(ProgressFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
          try
            L := Stream.Size;
            Max := 100*2014;
            if L > Max then
            begin
              Stream.Position := L - Max;
              L := Max;
            end;
            SetLength(Buffer, (L div 2) + (L mod 2));
            Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, L);
            S := BufferToAnsi(Buffer);
          finally
            Stream.Free;
          end;
        except
          Log(Format('Failed to read progress from file %s - %s', [
                     ProgressFileName, GetExceptionMessage]));
        end;
    end;

    if S <> '' then
      begin
        Log('Progress len = ' + IntToStr(Length(S)));
        Lines := TStringList.Create();
        Lines.Text := S;
        for I := 0 to Lines.Count - 1 do
        begin
          if I < ProgressListBox.Items.Count then
          begin
            ProgressListBox.Items[I] := Lines[I];
          end
            else
          begin
            ProgressListBox.Items.Add(Lines[I]);
          end
        end;
        ProgressListBox.ItemIndex := ProgressListBox.Items.Count - 1;
        ProgressListBox.Selected[ProgressListBox.ItemIndex] := False;
        Lines.Free;
      end;

    { Just to pump a Windows message queue (maybe not be needed) }
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 1);
  end;

procedure UpdateProgressProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; Event: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  UpdateProgress;
end;

procedure RunInstallBatInsideProgress;
  var
    ResultCode: Integer;
    Timer: LongWord;
    AppPath: string;
    AppError: string;
    Command: string;

  begin
    ProgressPage :=
      CreateOutputProgressPage(
        'Running ResetWU Script', 'Please wait until the script finishes...');
    ProgressPage.Show();
    ProgressListBox := TNewListBox.Create(WizardForm);
    ProgressListBox.Parent := ProgressPage.Surface;
    ProgressListBox.Top := 0;
    ProgressListBox.Left := 0;
    ProgressListBox.Width := ProgressPage.SurfaceWidth;
    ProgressListBox.Height := ProgressPage.SurfaceHeight;

    { Fake SetProgress call in UpdateProgressProc will show it, }
    { make sure that user won't see it }
    {ProgressPage.ProgressBar.Top := -100;}

    try
      Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 250, CreateCallback(@UpdateProgressProc));
      AppPath := ExpandConstant('C:\temp\myscript.cmd');
      ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('C:\Temp\install-progress.log');
      Log(Format('Expecting progress in %s', [ProgressFileName]));
      Command := Format('""%s" > "%s""', [AppPath, ProgressFileName]);
      if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/c ' + Command + ExpandConstant(' {app}\PIPE'), '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
        begin                                                   
          AppError := 'Cannot start app';
        end
      else
        if ResultCode <> 0 then
          begin
            AppError := Format('App failed with code %d', [ResultCode]);
          end;

      UpdateProgress;
      
    finally
        { Clean up }
        KillTimer(0, Timer);
        ProgressPage.Hide;
        DeleteFile(ProgressFileName);
        ProgressPage.Free();
    end;
     
    if AppError <> '' then
      begin 
        { RaiseException does not work properly while TOutputProgressWizardPage is shown }
        RaiseException(AppError);
      end;
  end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
  begin
    if CurStep=ssPostInstall then
      begin
           RunInstallBatInsideProgress;
      end
  end;  
 
// Add button to custom progress page. 
function GetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer): LongInt;
  external 'GetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer; NewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
  external 'SetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  GWL_STYLE = -16;
  BS_MULTILINE = $2000;
  
procedure StopButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('This is the stop message!', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();

var
  Button: TNewButton;
begin
  Button := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  Button.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - WizardForm.CancelButton.Left - WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
  Button.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  Button.Width := WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
  Button.Height := WizardForm.NextButton.Height;
  Button.Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;

  SetWindowLong(Button.Handle, GWL_STYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(Button.Handle, GWL_STYLE) or BS_MULTILINE);

  Button.Caption := 'Stop';
  Button.OnClick := @StopButtonOnClick;
end;
```

I have tried looking for the jrsoftware documentation, but I am quite new to this and can't understand it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to block the UI while running application (and if you want to be able to manipulate with [kill] the application), you cannot run it using the blocking `Exec` function.

Instead, you can use [`ShellExecuteEx` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) to run the application and then use [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) to query its status. The below code is stripped down version of [Inno Setup Get progress from .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) installer to update progress bar position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39247947/850848).

```pascal
const
  WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0;
  WAIT_TIMEOUT = $00000102;
  SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = $00000040;
  
function WaitForSingleObject(
  Handle: THandle; Milliseconds: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  external 'WaitForSingleObject@kernel32.dll stdcall';

type
  TShellExecuteInfo = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    fMask: Cardinal;
    Wnd: HWND;
    lpVerb: string;
    lpFile: string;
    lpParameters: string;
    lpDirectory: string;
    nShow: Integer;
    hInstApp: THandle;    
    lpIDList: DWORD;
    lpClass: string;
    hkeyClass: THandle;
    dwHotKey: DWORD;
    hMonitor: THandle;
    hProcess: THandle;
  end;

function ShellExecuteEx(var lpExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo): BOOL; 
  external 'ShellExecuteExW@shell32.dll stdcall';

function TerminateProcess(Process: THandle; ExitCode: Cardinal): Boolean;
  external 'TerminateProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;

procedure ExecWithoutBlocking;
var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  R: Cardinal;
  Completed: Boolean;
  AppError: string;
begin
  // Start the installer using ShellExecuteEx to get process ID
  ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
  ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
  ExecInfo.lpFile := 'notepad.exe';
  ExecInfo.lpParameters := '';
  ExecInfo.nShow := SW_SHOW;

  if not ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
    RaiseException('Cannot start');

  Log(Format('Program started as process %x', [ExecInfo.hProcess]));
  
  ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('Running program', '');
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 100);
  ProgressPage.Show;
  try
    Completed := False;

    while not Completed do
    begin
      // Check if the process has finished already
      R := WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, 0);
      if R = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      begin
        Log('Program completed');
        Completed := True;
      end
        else
      if R <> WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      begin
        AppError := 'Error waiting for program to complete';
        Completed := True;
      end;
      // Seemingly pointless as progress did not change,
      // but it pumps a message queue as a side effect
      ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 100);
      Sleep(100);
    end;
  finally
    ProgressPage.Hide;
  end;

  if AppError <> '' then
  begin 
    // RaiseException does not work properly
    // while TOutputProgressWizardPage is shown
    RaiseException(AppError);
  end;
end;
```

---

The `ShellExecuteEx` gives you a process ID, which you can use to stop/kill the process using [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess):

```pascal
procedure StopButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TerminateProcess(ExecInfo.hProcess, 0);
end;
```

---

If you want to combine it with output redirection to a custom page, you can do:

```pascal
procedure AbortButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TerminateProcess(ExecInfo.hProcess, 0);
end;

procedure RunInstallBatInsideProgress;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  AppPath: string;
  Command: string;
  Completed: Boolean;
  R: Integer;
  AppError: string;
  AbortButton: TButton;
begin
  ProgressPage :=
    CreateOutputProgressPage(
      'Running ResetWU Script', 'Please wait until the script finishes...');
  ProgressPage.Show();

  AbortButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AbortButton.Parent := ProgressPage.Surface;
  AbortButton.Caption := 'Abort';
  AbortButton.Top := ProgressPage.SurfaceHeight - AbortButton.Height - ScaleY(8);
  AbortButton.Left := 0;
  AbortButton.OnClick := @AbortButtonClick;

  ProgressListBox := TNewListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ProgressListBox.Parent := ProgressPage.Surface;
  ProgressListBox.Top := 0;
  ProgressListBox.Left := 0;
  ProgressListBox.Width := ProgressPage.SurfaceWidth;
  ProgressListBox.Height := AbortButton.Top - ScaleY(8);

  // Fake SetProgress call in UpdateProgress will show it,
  // make sure that user won't see it
  ProgressPage.ProgressBar.Top := -100;

  try
    ExtractTemporaryFile('install.bat');
    AppPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\install.bat');
    ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\progress.txt');
    Log(Format('Expecting progress in %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    Command := Format('""%s" > "%s""', [AppPath, ProgressFileName]);

    // Start the installer using ShellExecuteEx to get process ID
    ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
    ExecInfo.lpFile := ExpandConstant('{cmd}');
    ExecInfo.lpParameters := '/c ' + Command;
    ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

    if not ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
      RaiseException('Cannot start');

    Log(Format('Program started as process %x', [ExecInfo.hProcess]));
    
    Completed := False;

    while not Completed do
    begin
      // Check if the process has finished already
      R := WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, 0);
      if R = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      begin
        Log('Program completed');
        Completed := True;
      end
        else
      if R <> WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      begin
        AppError := 'Error waiting for program to complete';
        Completed := True;
      end;
      UpdateProgress;
      Sleep(100);
    end;

    UpdateProgress;
  finally
    ProgressPage.Hide;
    DeleteFile(ProgressFileName);
    ProgressPage.Free();
  end;
   
  if AppError <> '' then
  begin 
    // RaiseException does not work properly
    // while TOutputProgressWizardPage is shown
    RaiseException(AppError);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

- Note that contrary to the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56910906/850848), this does not need the "timer" code anymore, as the `UpdateProgress` can be called from the `while not Completed do` loop.
- The "Abort" button kills the process. You might want to introduce less violent abort mechanism. E.g. by creating a signal file that would cause the batch file to abort gracefully.