# Show custom error on Finish page in Inno Setup based on the exit code from a custom script

Tags: inno-setup

I am using following Inno Setup code to run a PowerShell script and redirect its output to custom progress page:
[Create a button on Inno Setup custom wizard page to interrupt an program executed from the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77051974/create-a-button-on-inno-setup-custom-wizard-page-to-interrupt-an-program-execute)

What I want is to show custom error messages on Finish page based on the errors thrown by PowerShell script instead of default Finish page with default message.

I have configured the PowerShell script to give specific error codes in case of specific failures. I have used something like this:

```bash
Write-Output $Error.Exception.Message
Exit 1000
```

Here 1000 is custom error code when script exits.

Is it possible to display custom error message on Finish page of Inno Setup based on the error code as shown above?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the exit code, use `GetExitCodeProcess`:

```pascal
function GetExitCodeProcess(Process: THandle; var ExitCode: Cardinal): Boolean;
  external 'GetExitCodeProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';
```

somewhere after the process completes. In your case, it's somewhere after the `while not Completed do` loop completes:

```pascal
var
  ExitCode: Cardinal;
```

```
GetExitCodeProcess(ExecInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
```

Then use the `ExitCode` to create or modify the labels on `WizardForm.FinishedPage`.